# Aftering .toggle() users click twice after using .mouseleave() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, return, toggle, mouseleave

When users toggle the `$('#menu');` button, they have no problem. However, when users mouseleaves the `$('#dropdown');` then click back the `$('#menu');` they have to click twice in order for the toggle to work again. Am I doing something wrong?

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BF8p6/)

===========HTML===========

```
<a class="" href="javascript:;" id="menu"></a>
<div style="display: none;" id="dropdown">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="menu-section">
      <div class="menu-header-section">
        <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-list">
        <ul class="list">
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="closeThis">close</a> </div>
</div>
```

===========jQuery===========

```
    //menu
var menu = $('#menu');
var dropdown = $('#dropdown');

menu.toggle(function () {
    menu.addClass('active');
    dropdown.fadeIn();
}, function () {
    menu.removeClass('active');
    dropdown.fadeOut();
    return false;
});
dropdown.mouseleave(function () {
    menu.removeClass('active');
    dropdown.fadeOut();
    return menu;
});
```

Comment: create a `jsFiddle`, gets a lot easier for us to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KvqMV/1/ this is what you need to start making :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) explain it all:

> **.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [, handler(eventObject)] )
>   handler(eventObject)** A function to execute every even time the element is clicked.
>   **handler(eventObject)** A function to execute every odd time the element is clicked.
>
> The .toggle() method binds a handler for the click event, so the rules outlined for the triggering of click apply here as well.

In other words, `toggle()` alternates based on even and odd `click` events. So:

- click [odd]: Show
- click [even]: Hide
- click 1: Show
- click 1: Show
- click 2: Hide
- click 3: Show
- click 4: Hide
- click 5: Show
- mouseleave: Hide
- click 6: Hide // Notice that `#dropdown` is already hidden here, but regardless, it's an **even** click. Click once, and you're hiding it again.
- click 7: Show // Click twice to show.

Anyways, that's the explenation for your problem. Working on solution.

---

**Solution**

Manually trigger the `click` event.

Replace:

```
dropdown.mouseleave(function () {
    menu.removeClass('active');
    dropdown.fadeOut();
    return menu;
});
```

With:

```
dropdown.mouseleave(function () {
    menu.trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/BF8p6/2/

Answer (score 1):

Logically,

You **first** click the `menu`, the `dropdown` appears. You `mouseleave` the `dropdown` (it disappears).

Now, when you click the `menu` **2nd time**, it executes the "2nd half" of the `.toggle()` function (i.e `.fadeOut()` the `dropdown`).

After this, when you click the `menu` again, it executes the "first half" of the `.toggle()` and all seems merry.

**EDIT**

You can try and use the concept of `flag`.

```
var menu = $('#menu');
var dropdown = $('#dropdown');
var flag = 'reset';

menu.click(function () {
    if(flag == 'reset')
    {
        menu.addClass('active');
        dropdown.fadeIn();
        flag = 'set';
    }
    else if(flag =='set')
    {
        flag = 'reset'; 
        menu.removeClass('active');
        dropdown.fadeOut();                               
        return false;
    }
});

dropdown.mouseleave(function () {
    flag = 'reset';
    menu.removeClass('active');
    dropdown.fadeOut();
    return menu;
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BF8p6/1/

Comment: Half way...  How do I return to the 1st half of the toggle?

Comment: Tested in Firefox, it's a bit buggy.

Comment: It's doing the same thing. I also tested it in IE7, no dice. I have to click twice in order for the toggle to work again

Comment: can you debug and check the `flag` values whether they're getting altered correctly? I'll take a while to check on FX and IE7

Comment: I'm saying it's not completely working. It's doing exactly what I started with.

Comment: posted the code in my answer? it's working fine on the fiddle link though

Comment: It lags after mouseleaves, then trying to click the  $('#menu');
 it does the same thing that I have set up. This works better..... http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/BF8p6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```
$('#menu').click(
function () {

if ($("#dropdown:visible"))
{
$('.mapNavLeft').removeClass("active");
$(this).next('#dropdown')fadeOut();
} else {
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).next('#dropdown')fadeIn();
}

});

$("#dropdown").hover(
function () {
  return false;
},
function () {
  $(this).fadeOut();
}
);
```